# How to set Background image to AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avvideocomposition

I  set the `backgroundColor` its Working fine, but i am not able to set the background image.

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,assetWithMaxTime.duration);
mainInstruction.enablePostProcessing = NO;

mainInstruction.backgroundColor =[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689861/avfoundation-uiimage-behind-video-track

Comment: did u get any solution? I am also facing same problem...

Comment: @emraz did you solve it eventually? We are stuck also..

Comment: @RoiMulia yes I did, Please follow the code as I describe in my answer. The given solution is working fine...

Comment: @emraz Is it efficient tho? As it takes 2 exports to finish the process. Sorry for asking

Comment: @RoiMulia Actually I didn't get any other solution :(. And this is the only way I got to work.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several things finally I got a way to work it. To make it work need to use a blank video/audio track. Then add background image an overlay to this blank video layer. Ten export it and combine the original asset(video) and exported asset(asset) and export the final asset(video).

**Add overlay**

```
- (void)addOverlayImage:(UIImage *)overlayImage ToVideo:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)composition inSize:(CGSize)size {
    // 1 - set up the overlay
    CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];

    [overlayLayer setContents:(id)[overlayImage CGImage]];
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    // 2 - set up the parent layer
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

    // 3 - apply magic
    composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                                 videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
}

- (void)getBackgroundVideoAssetWithcompletion:(void (^)(AVAsset *bgAsset))completionBlock {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"blank_video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *trackUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:trackUrl];
    AVAssetTrack *track = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

    CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]);
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:range ofTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];


    CGAffineTransform videoTransform = track.preferredTransform;
    CGSize naturalSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(track.naturalSize, videoTransform);
    naturalSize = CGSizeMake(fabs(naturalSize.width), fabs(naturalSize.height));


    AVMutableVideoComposition *composition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithPropertiesOfAsset:asset];
    UIImage *img = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white_image"] convertToSize:naturalSize];
    [self addOverlayImage:img ToVideo:composition inSize:naturalSize];


    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    instruction.timeRange = range;
    composition.instructions = @[instruction];


    AVAssetExportSession *_assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    _assetExport.videoComposition = composition;



    NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"exported-%d.mov", arc4random() % 100000]];
    unlink([exportPath UTF8String]);
    NSURL *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

    _assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    _assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
    _assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        switch (_assetExport.status) {

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                 break;

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting:
                break;

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"Successful!!!");
                    AVAsset *finalAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:_assetExport.outputURL];
                    completionBlock(finalAsset);
                });
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
}
```

Now there is a video asset with an overlay image. Only thing is remain to combine original video and the exported video asset. Exported asset should be bottom layer and original should be top layer.